# Trying to add Weblogic plugin configuration on IntelliJ

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, weblogic

I created image of weblogic on docker now I am trying to connect it through plugin on intellij. The connection says OK but when I run my project it asks me for a Weblogic server home path. But I don't the path because it's inside the docker. I am using UBUNTU
see image

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA app server integrations require a local server installation on the same machine where IDE is running so that it can index and use the libraries of this app server.